# extract each word from list of strings

Tags: python

I am using Python
my list is

```
str = ["Hello dude", "What is your name", "My name is Chetan"]
```

I want to separate each word in each sentence in the string and store it in new_list. new_list will be like

```
new_list = ["Hello", "dude", "What", "is", "your", "name", "My", "name", 
            "is", "Chetan"]
```

I tried with the code

```
for row in str:
    new_list.append(row.split(" "))
```

Output:

```
[['Hello', 'dude'], ['What', 'is', 'your', 'name'], ['My', 'name', 'is', 
  'Chetan']]
```

which is list of list

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name, you are masking the builtin `str`

Comment: This interests me going from Python to Haskell, as it's one of the very few bits of code that's more terse in Haskell than in Python. `concatMap words originalList`

Comment: `split()` instead of `split(' ')` will handle cases of multiple continuous whitespace characters

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
from itertools import chain

def split_list_of_words(list_):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, list_)))
```

**DEMO**

```
input_ = [
          "Hello dude", 
          "What is your name", 
          "My name is Chetan"
         ]

result = split_list_of_words(input_)

print(result)
#['Hello', 'dude', 'What', 'is', 'your', 'name', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Chetan']
```

Answer (score 2):

you have,

```
values = ["Hello dude", "What is your name", "My name is Chetan"]
```

then use this one liner

```
' '.join(values).split()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help. Instead of append use `extend` or `+=`

```
str = ["Hello dude", "What is your name", "My name is Chetan"]
new_list = []
for row in str:
    new_list += row.split(" ") #or new_list.extend(row.split(" "))

print new_list
```

**Output**:

```
['Hello', 'dude', 'What', 'is', 'your', 'name', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Chetan']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. All that's left to do is to un-nest your list.

```
final_result = [x for sublist in new_list for x in sublist]
```

Or without a list comprehension:

```
final_result = []
for sublist in new_list:
    for x in sublist:
        final_result.append(x)
```

Of course, all of this can be done in a single step without producing `new_list` first explicitly. The other answers already covered that.

Comment: you haven't called `split` here.

Comment: @AdamSmith My starting point is OP's `new_list` `[['Hello', 'dude'], ['What', 'is', 'your', 'name'], ['My', 'name', 'is', 'Chetan']]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_list = [x for y in str for x in y.split(" ")]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:-**

```
str = ["Hello dude", "What is your name", "My name is Chetan"]
ls = []
for i in str:
    x = i.split()
    ls +=x
print(ls)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> new_list=[]
>>> str = ["Hello dude", "What is your name", "My name is Chetan"]
>>> for row in str:
      for data in row.split():
        new_list.append(data)

>>> new_list
['Hello', 'dude', 'What', 'is', 'your', 'name', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Chetan']
```